# Oracle DB 12c to 19c Migrations - Which things to take care of from application point of view

Tags: oracle, migration

We have instructions to move from 12c to 19c Oracle Enterprise database. From Application point of view what things we should take care of. I want to know which oracle features will be missing in 19c when we are migrating from 12c?

Comment: Please find the guide to ugrade https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/upgrd/

Answer (score 1):

If you follow these links:

[Changes in This Release for Oracle Database SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Changes-in-This-Release-for-Oracle-Database-SQL-Language-Reference.html#GUID-2D6EBFD3-88AC-4AA0-B9C2-B3E41A8F30FB)

[Changes in This Release for Oracle Database PL/SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/release-changes.html#GUID-A9DDE39A-64DB-496E-BCCF-4585C7E064AF)

you'll see what's deprecated and/or desupported in 19c version. Those are SQL and PL/SQL stuff (as you asked for *developers*). Other documentation also contains similar chapters so - if you're interested - search for them.